# in loopback nodejs, before save check the month is enter with same userid

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I create a module and add some properties, if same month will update in the same user id, have to show error, I don't have any idea to check the month is already inserted or not [image]

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you have just asked, but I will try to help you anyway. If I understand correctly you need unique month/userId combination? If that is a case, then you can use unique index in your model where you can include those two fields. If not, please try to better explain your question, otherwise people will not be able to help you.

Comment: ok. for example, if I add January(month) for one user-111, again I add the same month for the same user it can't post, show some error. do you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer. duplicate entry can find by using before save.

```
module.exports = function(Payslip) {
var app = require('../../server/server');
    Payslip.validatesPresenceOf('userId');
        var username_;
        var userId;
    Payslip.observe('before save', function(ctx, next){
        userId = ctx.instance.userId;

        app.models.User.findOne({where :{'id': userId}}, function(err, res){
            username_ = res.username.replace(/\s/g,'-');
            username_ = username_;

        var fileName = username_+"-Payslip-"+ctx.instance.month+"-"+ctx.instance.year;
        ctx.instance.fileName = fileName;

        Payslip.findOne({where: {'fileName': fileName}}, function(err, ctx){
            if(ctx){
                next('Found duplicate entry');
            }
            else{
                next();
            }
        })
    })
 });
};
```